# Can't use embed font

Tags: haxe, openfl

I'm doing everything just like in the instruction.

Class Fonts.hx

```
import flash.text.Font;

@:font("assets/fonts/OPENSANS-REGULAR_0.TTF") class OpenSansFont extends Font { }

class Fonts 
{
    public static inline var OPEN_SANS_PATH = "assets/fonts/OPENSANS-REGULAR_0.TTF";
    public static inline var OPEN_SANS_FONTNAME = "OPENSANS-REGULAR_0.TTF";

    public function new()
    {
        Font.registerFont(OpenSansFont);
    }
}
```

But when I try create TextFormat with this:

```
var tf:TextFormat;
var openSans:Font = Assets.getFont(Fonts.OPEN_SANS_PATH);
tf = new TextFormat(openSans.fontName);
```

I catch this error:

> Assets.hx:257: [openfl.Assets] There is no Font asset with an ID of
>   "assets/fonts/OPENSANS-REGULAR_0.TTF"

What am I doing wrong?

My project structure:

[image: My project structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `openfl.Assets` for Assets embedded via `@:font` / `@:bitmap` etc.

You should use the font's name for the `TextFormat` constructor. I assume you've already tried that, seeing how there's an `OPEN_SANS_FONTNAME` variable. However, that's not the *font's name*, just its *file name*.

On Windows, you should be able to find out the name by double-clicking on the font (right under the print / install buttons).

Alternatively, this should work as well:

```
import flash.text.Font;

@:font("assets/fonts/OPENSANS-REGULAR_0.TTF") class OpenSansFont extends Font { }

class Fonts 
{
    public static var OPEN_SANS_FONTNAME;

    public function new()
    {
        Font.registerFont(OpenSansFont);
        OPEN_SANS_FONTNAME = new OpenSansFont().fontName;
    }
}
```

Comment: in the code snippet above, did you mean to import "flash.text.Font" or "openfl.text.Font"? I've tried code like this but (with either import) the fontName property just returns "LIME_font_OpenSansFont".

Comment: openfl.* maps to flash.*, the imports are equivalent. Does that happen on all targets?